# Invalid URL in iOS SDK Deezer player

Tags: deezer

I have problem with **iOS SDK** from **Deezer**. I initialize a connection with Deezer:

```
_deez = [[DeezerConnect alloc] initWithAppId:kDeezerAppId andDelegate:self];

// List of permissions available from the Deezer SDK web site */
NSMutableArray* permissionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"basic_access", @"offline_access", @"manage_library", @"delete_library", nil];

[_deez authorize:permissionsArray];
```

Login is successfull.
After login I want to initialize a player I use:

```
 _player = [PlayerFactory createPlayer];
[_player setPlayerDelegate:self];
[_player setBufferDelegate:self];
 [_player preparePlayerForTrackWithDeezerId:trackid
                                    stream:stream
                          andDeezerConnect:_deez];
```

And I get in bufferDidFailWithError:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x194370a0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x190894f0 "unsupported URL"}
```

Maybe the problem is in stream. What is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to listen to an album or a playlist, do you check the "readable" value received with each track object ?

Example of JSon received for a track :

```
    tracks =     {
         data =         (
                    {
            artist =                 {
                id = 1234;
                name = toto;
            };
            duration = 1;
            id = 6789;
            link = "";
            preview = "";
            rank = 1;
            readable = 0;
            stream = 0;
            title = Title;
            type = track;
        },
```

If "readable" and "stream" are both equals to false, you can not read the track.

Comment: My song is readable in my country and received JSON for a track do not have a stream value. Stream is something different. On Deezer developer site is only NSString *stream = @"abdcdef";, but no example what it is.

Comment: Typically the stream represents the value of the stream object received with the JSon. If you don't have it, you can not listen to the track.

What do you want to play ? Are-you into connected mode or not ?
If not, you only can listen to track's preview.

Comment: So player finally works :), the stream value is only in json from Deezer request not in URL request. Thanks for answers.